# Is there an easier way to debug this server firmware?

Tags: javascript, c, server

I've written a javascript web app to be hosted on a Lantronix Xport Pro embedded device server. The problem I'm having is with sending requests to a cgi-handling firmware program in C using Lantronix's EvolutionOS SDK (https://cdn.lantronix.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/Evolution-OS-SDK.pdf)

I'm getting a 400 error, where the POST request seems to be getting sent from the client just fine, but the server is having trouble parsing it, maybe?

Here is my server-side code:

```
static bool WebMgrCallback(struct http_client *httpClient)
{
    const char *contentType = HttpGetHeader(httpClient, "Content-Type");
    // const char *contentLength = HttpGetHeader(httpClient, "Content-Length");
    bool post = false;
    
    /* Process multipart POST data. */
    if (contentType && strcmp(HttpGetRequestMethodType(httpClient), "POST") == 0)
    {
        // Check if the content type is multipart/form-data
        if (strcmp(contentType, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") == 0)
        {
            // Check if the content length is valid
            if(HttpDecodeQueryData(httpClient, HttpGetRequestBodyData(httpClient)))
            {
                post = true;
            }
...

    if(strcmp(HttpGetRequestUri(httpClient), "/api"))
    {
        // TODO: should I further break down the uri into api parts? [pos, fp, password, etc.]
        char *allocatedBuffer = NULL;

        // if the request is a POST, then we need to check the content type
        if(post)        
        {
            allocatedBuffer = sampleWebMgrPost_malloc(httpClient);
        }
        
        sampleWebMgrHandlePost(httpClient, allocatedBuffer);
...
    return true;
}

static char *WebMgrPost_malloc(struct http_client *httpClient)
{
    char *buffer = NULL;
    const char *cmd = HttpGetQueryVar(httpClient, "cmd");
    const char *password = HttpGetQueryVar(httpClient, "password");
    const char *confpass = HttpGetQueryVar(httpClient, "confpass");

    
    if (cmd)
    {
        memcpy(buffer, cmd, sizeof(cmd));
        if (password) 
        {
            memcpy(buffer + sizeof(cmd), TEXT_NEW_LINE, SIZEOF_NL);
            memcpy(buffer + sizeof(cmd) + SIZEOF_NL, password, sizeof(password));
            if (confpass) 
            {
                memcpy(buffer + sizeof(cmd) + SIZEOF_NL + sizeof(password), 
                        TEXT_NEW_LINE, SIZEOF_NL);
                memcpy(buffer + sizeof(cmd) + SIZEOF_NL + sizeof(password) + SIZEOF_NL, 
                        confpass, sizeof(confpass));
            }
        }
    }
    
    return buffer;
}


static void WebMgrHandlePost(struct http_client *httpClient, char *buffer)
{
    // send POST data to RS232
    if(! SerialOpen(SERIAL_PORT))
    {
        TLOG(TLOG_SEVERITY_ERR, "Failed to open serial port.");
        return;
    } 

    if (! SerialWrite(SERIAL_PORT, buffer, strlen(buffer), true)) {
        TLOG(TLOG_SEVERITY_ERR, "Failed to write to serial port.");
    }

    SerialClose(SERIAL_PORT);

}
```

And below is my js

```
const _syncTransmit = function(command) {
  req.open("POST", "http://" + testServerAddress + ":" + connectionPort + "/api", false);
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  // req.setRequestHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
  

  let message = "cmd=" + command;

  req.send(JSON.stringify
```

To make things worse, I'm unsure what any of the error details mean

```
POST http://10.0.0.136/api 400 (Bad Request: Unknown Request)
z @ telnet_xmlhttpreq.js:64
(anonymous) @ telnet_xmlhttpreq.js:84
c @ regeneratorRuntime.js:44
(anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:125
(anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:69
L @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
o @ asyncToGenerator.js:22
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:27
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:19
(anonymous) @ telnet_xmlhttpreq.js:73
H @ telnet_xmlhttpreq.js:199
(anonymous) @ Switch.js:74
au @ react-dom.production.min.js:244
Ss @ react-dom.production.min.js:286
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:282
k @ scheduler.production.min.js:13
M @ scheduler.production.min.js:14
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you set `"Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` but send `JSON.stringify ... the rest of this has disappeared` ... the issue is likely you're sending the wrong content - see, an error 400 means `that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (for example, malformed request syntax ....` which you are definitely guilty of